# Below given javascript and jquery functions in not working in MAC safari but it is working in all other devices and browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var slideInd = 1;
showDiv(slideInd);

function plusDiv(m) {
  showDiv(slideInd += m);
}

function currentDivs(m) {
  showDiv(slideInd = m);
}

function showDiv(m) {
  var j;
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (m > y.length) {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = '1' + ' of 3';
  } else if (m < 1) {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = y.length + ' of 3';
  } else if (m >= 1) {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = slideInd + ' of 3';
  }

  if (m > y.length) {
    slideInd = 1
  }
  if (m < 1) {
    slideInd = y.length
  }
  for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
    y[j].style.display = "none";
  }
  y[slideInd - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlides">
<img class="animation-element slide-down-3 img-responsive" src="https://cdn.msisurfaces.com/images/lookbook/invincibles/car3/gris-antoni-porcelain.jpg">
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
<img class="animation-element slide-down-1 img-responsive" src="https://cdn.msisurfaces.com/images/lookbook/invincibles/car3/cafe-antoni-porcelain.jpg">
</div>
<div class="mySlides">
<img class="animation-element slide-down-1 img-responsive" src="https://cdn.msisurfaces.com/images/lookbook/invincibles/car6/prescott-katella-ash-vinyl-flooring.jpg">
</div>

<div id="arrow1" class="arrow-rgt">

<a class="" onclick="plusDiv(-1)"><img class="img-responsive arrow-left" src="https://cdn.msisurfaces.com/images/lookbook/arrow-left-half.png"></a>

<span class="arrow-span" id="out"></span>

<a class="" onclick="plusDiv(1)"><img class="img-responsive arrow-right" src="https://cdn.msisurfaces.com/images/lookbook/arrow-right-half.png"></a>
   </div>
```

Given javascript function is working fine in all the browsers and all the devices except in mac safari browser
But if i open inspect element is safari browser then this function work without any error if i close the inspect element tab then it wont work

Please help me out in this

Above span tag is not working only in mac book safari

Comment: What exactly is “not working”? Have you checked the console for errors? Why is `m` not properly declared as a global variable? Also, please provide a _proper_ [mcve]. Right now, your snippet is not even showing any “arrows”. Either supply images somewhere online, so they work in a snippet - or replace them with something else, so that those links at least show up.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where on the page is the code? Consider putting it all the way at the bottom.

Comment: <span class="arrow-span" id="out"> </span>

Comment: <span class="arrow-span" id="out"> </span>